# Possible Bijection Between Natural and Real Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I'm studying the Cantor diagonal argument showing that there isn't any function $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ in one-to-one with each other and accepted it.
But, thinking about it for awhile, I thought in a function $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ in binary base, that is just the identity function:
$$f(1) = 1$$
$$f(10) = 10$$
$$f(11) = 11$$
$$f(100) = 100$$
$$f(101) = 101$$
$$\dots$$
So, what's wrong if I define the following function:
$$f(1) = 0.1$$
$$f(10) = 0.01$$
$$f(11) = 0.11$$
$$f(100) = 0.001$$
$$f(101) = 0.101$$
$$\dots$$

Where the only difference is that the digits are written in reverse order.
Why the latter defined $f$ doesn't maps $\mathbb N$ in the real interval $(0,1]$?

Comment: For which $x \in \mathbb N$ do you think $\,f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\,$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Your function maps $\mathbb N$ into but not onto the real interval $(0,1)$; for example, it doesn't map any natural number to $0.1111111...$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner technically $0.1111\ldots=1\notin(0,1)$ but your point stands with something like $0.0101010101\ldots$

Comment: @pancini:  your point is well-taken

Comment: @pancini you are right. I include 1 in the interval. But the question remains.

Comment: @AdrianoFarias the question has already been answered twice.

Comment: @pancini, can you point me out the link to the answer to my question that was already answered? And $0.010101\dots$ converges to 1/3.

Comment: @AdrianoFarias "*0.010101… converges to 1/3*" $-$ Right, but you can't find an $x$ such that $f(x)=1/3$ or $f(x) = \sqrt{2} / {2}$ because, by construction, all values that $f(x)$ takes must have a finite binary representation i.e. must be fractions of the form $a / 2^n$ for some $a, n \in \mathbb N$. That's a countable subset of the reals in $(0,1)$, but far from *all* reals in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that the real numbers are countable: Help with why this is wrong](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61174/proof-that-the-real-numbers-are-countable-help-with-why-this-is-wrong). It is in fact the first post linked under the *Related* column on the right-hand side next to your question.

Comment: This is also asked and answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3712794/139123